# How to pass variable from a database query to a PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, function, variables

get_population($row['ID']) is causing error Variable undefined:

```
foreach($filterList as $row)
{
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>' . $row['county_ID'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . get_population($row['ID']) . '</td>'; 
   echo '<td>' . $row['ID'] . '</td>';     
   echo '</tr>';
}
```

When I use a database value in the function parameter I get the error :Undefined variable:
It must be out of scope but I don't know how to get around it.

If I print $row['ID'] it shows the value of 1 for this example. If I hard code 1 as the parameter value it works. It is only when I try to pass $row['ID'] to the function that I get the error.

I am sure it is a simple answer but I am chasing my tail.  Thanks

Comment: Can we see your query? Perhaps the table structure? The get_population() function?

Comment: Might be you're getting the error _inside_ the `get_population()` function? Can you post that too?

Comment: Are you missing $row in front of ['ID']?

Comment: Please post the whole error message. Undefined variable warnings contain the name of the variable that's undefined.

Comment: The error message also has a line number. Please point out the specific line that's getting the error.

Comment: In your database, is it 'ID' or 'Id' or 'id' ? Be careful to that...

Comment: First of all, thanks for taking a look at my problem.If I pass 1 to the get_population() it works as expected.  If I print $row['ID'] it shows a value of 1.  I did make the mistake of pasting ['ID'] in my post, I corrected it with $row['ID'] but that is not the problem with my code, I edited my post.  I did not post the full code because I did not want to make it harder to read.

Comment: can we see the code behind your get_population function?

Answer (score 1):

In your code there's a mismatch in ''.['ID'].'';

The correct is $row['ID']:

```
foreach($filterList as $row)
{
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>' . $row['county_ID'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . get_population($row['ID']) . '</td>'; 
   // error here
   echo '<td>' . ['ID'] . '</td>';     
   // change with
   echo '<td>' . $row['ID'] . '</td>';     
   echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: I suspect that's a copying error, because that would cause a parse error, not undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, the problem was a null value in the database.  Since there was no value to pass to the function it returned variable undefined.